# How to get whole number when dividing 2 numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing paging in JavaScript,

Now if I have `total_item_count = 69` and I want 10 records per page then it should show 7 pages but it is showing 6 pages.

What I am doing:

```
var totalpages = 69/10 ; // it should give 7 but its giving 6
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to make use od Math.ceil () function

Comment: @Smartboy Why? floor would give you 6.

Comment: how to downvote a comment?

Comment: @Smartboy: The logic here compels the use of `ceil` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var Totalpages = Math.ceil(Total Records/ Records per Page);
```

Here:

```
var Totalpages = Math.ceil(69/10);   // gives 7
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the upper integer you can use `ceil`:

```
var totalpages = Math.ceil(69/10);
```

Comment: Also you can floor with `~~` and ceil with `-~`. `total = -~(69/10)`.

Comment: @elclanrs Those should only be used for nasty interview questions =p

Comment: Never saw this notation before, good to know! But I agree with Jack, could be kinda confusing to see that in code.

Comment: I do agree as well. I use `~~` to floor in one liners but not `-~` for ceiling because it's easily confused.

Comment: @TimPetricola: It's not really special notation, it's just a trick with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var totalpages = Math.ceil(69/10) ;
```

> ceil(): Round a number upward to it's nearest integer:

Answer (score 1):

use `Math.ceil`  to get the upper integer.

`Math.ceil(69/10)` should give you 7